# I had discovered a math formula (finding the fourth vertex of a parallelogram). How to publish?

Tags: analytic-geometry, publishing

I am 16yr old and found a new math formula of finding fourth vertices of a parallelogram.

I am finding difficulty to publish that. I had read many website for publishing and tried many times. If you can tell the way for publishing the formula.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your formula here?  Knowing it might help folks answer.

Comment: Well, I don’t think this is a new formula. If we have point $a,b,c$ with $ab$ and $ac$ two of the lines of the parallelogram, then the fourth point is $b+c-a.$

Comment: You might consider checking to make sure this formula has not already been formalized, and/or generalized. It's possible that it has not, but perhaps it has and so it's required that you do research on this formula of yours.

Comment: Yes, how can you be sure it's a "new math formula"?

Answer (score 6):

I would highly recommend you spend some time to look through textbooks/literature to see if this is indeed a new discovery. If so, you could always publish your paper on [arXiv](http://arxiv.org) and proceed from there.

However, it would probably be best/easiest to simply post your work here first. That way you can benefit from any feedback you receive from users here and maybe even receive inspiration for where to look next in your studies. After all, since posts here are archived with timestamps, there is no reason to worry about someone plagiarizing your work.

Best of luck!